# clamav for android

Tags: android

Has anyone tried porting clamav to android??

Answer (score 1):

Still no clamdroid yet, but I hope someone (I'm looking at you Sourcefire) is working on it.
Though I think that [a Spybot-SD](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=%20Spybot%20Sd) type application is probably more useful and more important.

Remember: clamav is opensource, so **you** *can* port it to andoid yourself.

Answer (score -1):

We have to plans at this time to develop an Android solution for ClamAV. We have a commercial solution for Android, but it is not open source, and not ClamAV based.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: As the community manager for ClamAV, I'm directly answering the "looking at you Sourcefire" portion of the comment.  Since I'm probably the most qualified person to answer said question.